# $_POST is null when sending base64 images through form in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have an image upload script that uses croppie, it crops an image and generate a base64 string that i put on a hidden input and send to the server that i have with codeigniter and php, once it's there i decode and upload it, the code works BUT for some reason there a some images that when i upload them $_POST becomes null and the server doesn't receive anything

I check online and it looked like a issue with post_max_size and did a check up with

```php
    if ( !empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']) && empty($_POST) ){
        throw new Exception('PHP discarded POST data because of request   exceeding post_max_size, '.ini_get("upload_max_filesize"));
    } else {
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
```

it returns the exception but that's about it, the image isn't really that long and i have upgraded my hosting to the max amount that i could

```
    post_max_size                   128M
    suhosin.post.max_value_length   3000000
    suhosin.post.max_vars           3000000
    suhosin.request.max_vars    3000000
    upload_max_filesize             1G
```

But this hasn't fix my problem, i tried researching this issue a bit more but to no avail

This is the form

```php
    <?php                    
            echo form_open_multipart('disco/registrar');
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-12">            
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Crear un evento </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div>
                            <label for="titulo" class="col-md-4">
                                Nombre* :
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" name="titulo" placeholder="Digite un nombre" required
                                oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por digite un nombre')"
                                oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                            </div>  
                        </div>                  
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div>
                            <label for="descripcion" class="col-md-4">
                                Descripción* :
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="dir" placeholder="Digite una dirección" required
                                oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por digite una descripción')"
                                oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div>
                            <label for="extra" class="col-md-4">
                                Información adicional :
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="extra" name="extra" placeholder="Digite la información adicional" rows="3">
                                </textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div>
                            <label for="date" class="col-md-4">
                                Seleccione hasta cuando estara disponible la promoción* :
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">      
                                <div class="form-group">                            
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" required
                                    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor seleccione una fecha')"
                                    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="logo" class="col-md-4">
                                Seleccione una imagen* :
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-8"> 
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="file" id="logo" name="logo" class="file">
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>              
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <center>
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="" id="imgPlace" style="max-width: 100% !important;">
                                    </div>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h4>
                                    <p class="text-primary">Los campos marcados con * son obligatorios.</p>
                                </h4>
                                <?php 
                                if(null !== $this->session->flashdata('Error')){
                                    echo('<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger col-md-12-">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                        <strong>El numero de preguntas no es número mayor que 0.</strong>
                                        </div>
                                        <br>');
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <center>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="croppedData" id="croppedData" value="">
                                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="btnquiz" id="btnquiz" >Registrar</button>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </form>
```

The croppie script

```
    function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#imgPlace').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    $('#imgPlace').css({
                        height: '100%'
                    });
                    var uploadCrop = $('#imgPlace').croppie({
                        enableExif: true,
                        viewport: {
                            width: 800,
                            height: 600
                        },
                        boundary: {
                            width: 1024,
                            height: 1024
                        },
                        update: function (data) {
                            uploadCrop.croppie('result', 'base64', 'viewport', 'png').then(function(newImg) {
                                $('#croppedData').val(newImg);
                                console.log(newImg);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    uploadCrop.bind({
                        url: e.target.result,
                    });

                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

            }
        }
```

The Server

```php
    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/products/';
    $imgData = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $this->input->post('croppedData')));
    $characters =  '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    $randomString .= ".jpg";
    file_put_contents($dir . $randomString, $imgData);
```

As i said before this code works but there are some image that just wont go through such as [this one](https://eventsiteimage.s3.amazonaws.com/sitegaleries/254/files/blog/trinidad-casa-latina.jpg?1501508753)

Comment: Well first question, is the image getting uploaded? Look at your browser inspector and check the request.

Comment: @miken32 - same thing, just like to add in most browsers you can hit `f12` and then go to a `network` panel in the browser dev tools and view the actual request to see that the data is being sent.  This will give you an idea if the problem is in the Javascript (Client side) or on the Servers end.

Comment: The request on that particular image is null, any other image uploads without problem

Comment: The obvious question is what is significantly different about that one image, `size`, file type `jpg,png,gif` etc.  Perhaps that file is just corrupt etc..  Maybe you have a lager image for this, or maybe it's a `bmp` instead of a `jpg` etc...

Comment: I'm checked the image but couldn't find anything weird its a jpg 750x500px and fairly small at 74kb, i have edited and change formats but it wont upload, i just grayscaled it and it uploaded

Comment: Do files get added to the server anyway, when it fails?  Check the size, if they are tiny maybe they actually contain an error message in text format that you could read in an editor.

Comment: Since it make a random name and put the file it uploads it but it empty and show 0b on size